# Android- what's the difference between (button.Click += event;) and a (button.SetOnClickListener(this))?

Tags: android, xamarin, events, button, interface

They both do they same job- define what happens when clicking a button.
So, what's the real difference between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xamarin creates C# wrappers in many places within the Android (and iOS) frameworks that normalizes the platform's native methods to standard .Net/C# conventions.

`SetOnClickListener` is the native Java method and the C# `Click` is a `EventHandler` wrapper for the native method.

The code behind the Click event handler:

```
public event EventHandler Click {
    add {
        EventHelper.AddEventHandler (ref weak_implementor_SetOnClickListener, (Func<IOnClickListenerImplementor>)__CreateIOnClickListenerImplementor, (Action<IOnClickListener>)SetOnClickListener, (Action<IOnClickListenerImplementor>)delegate (IOnClickListenerImplementor __h) {
            __h.Handler = (EventHandler)Delegate.Combine (__h.Handler, value);
        });
    }
    remove {
        EventHelper.RemoveEventHandler (ref weak_implementor_SetOnClickListener, (Func<IOnClickListenerImplementor, bool>)IOnClickListenerImplementor.__IsEmpty, (Action<IOnClickListener>)delegate {
            SetOnClickListener (null);
        }, (Action<IOnClickListenerImplementor>)delegate (IOnClickListenerImplementor __h) {
            __h.Handler = (EventHandler)Delegate.Remove (__h.Handler, value);
        });
    }
}
```

As you can see in the code, `SetOnClickListener` is the more efficient approach as it avoids the wrapper.

Comment: So basically they both do the exact same job but in different ways?

Comment: @DanielReyhanian "...but in different ways..." I would say "at a different level", with the Click/EventHandler being the furtherest away from the native Java method and the C# SetOnClickListener the closest to the Java call. So in the end, yes, same result as your code knows the button was touched, but how many layers did it take to get there...